# Custom global variable in APEX?

Tags: apex

I'm not sure if the Apex classes provided what I'm looking for, so I have a situation where I want to store some custom appId as soon as the user login to the site and maintained on all other classes for later use, I thought of using the custom settings but the problem i ran into is that, the appId is different for Web/Mobile. I was using custom settings with upsert but that will not work the reason is that, if A login to the web site then will write on custom settings but then B login to the site with mobile then I will override again.

so not sure what approach is best here, any help?

Comment: Static method that returns correct value based on current page or whatever way you tell which one to return. Global as well

Comment: so in the landing page, if i set the value on a global static method that value will be persistence across all the classes?

Comment: Seems like hierarchy settings should be fine for your needs.

Comment: You could set a custom cookie, but that would only happen as soon as you had a VF page to set it from.

Comment: @sfdcfox: I did not understand, what do you mean "as soon as you had VF page to set"

Comment: @NickKahn When you log in, you end up wherever you end up (usually Home, but could be configured for any tab). However, once you land on a Visualforce page, you could set a cookie in Apex, which would persist across all page views on a specific browser.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: I did tried first with custom settings but not sure how would you do hierarchy, don't you have to select profile or user when you do set hierarchy? I've not done this before. if you think it will solve my problem, can you please show me how to do setup the settings?

Comment: It kind of sounds like you just need one key per user? Or is it one per device?

Comment: one key per user

Comment: @NickKahn It sounds like you want one key per *device*, because you were asking about what happens when a user logs in from two different devices?

Comment: @sfdcfox: the reason i said one key per user is because at a time one user will be using the app, so the choice of user to use phone or go to web site for in that sense i said one key per user, yes chances are there user might use tow different devices but its very low

Comment: You can set cookies from the home page fwiw.

Comment: @AdrianLarson/sfdcfox: can you set cookies alive till the user is on the site and as soon as it close kill the cookies?, i was reading about the cookies age but does not seems to have that option, they have age in terms of time

Comment: or i can override the cookies when creating from login page?